# Symfony2 cron job command in VPS

Tags: symfony, cron, cron-task, cronexpression

I have symfony2 project which I moved from a shared host to a VPS. I had a cron job command working in the shared host but I am unable to make it work in the VPS (WHM/cpanel CentOs 6).

The command I used in cpanel in the shared host was:

```
/usr/local/php-5.6.12/bin/php /home/a155r66t/public_html/mydomain.com/app/console api:import
```

In the VPS the route to the Symfony command is */home/mydomain.com/app/console api:import* but I am unable to find which would be the route to the php in VPS. I tried these with no success:

```
/usr/local/php-5.5.29/bin/php /home/mydomain.com/app/console api:import
/usr/bin/php
/usr/local/bin/php
root php
```

Can you please indicate how could i find the correct route to the php? Or what should it be? Thanks.

Comment: `whereis php` or `which php`

Comment: Thank you. It is a big step. The results for those SSH commands are:            **whereis php**
`php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php.ini /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/lib/php.ini,v /     
usr/local/lib/php.ini /usr/local/lib/php /usr/local/php`

**which php**
`/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: Most of those routes I already tried. The only examples I did not try: `/usr/local/bin/php` gives this error _/bin/sh: /usr/local/lib/php: is a directory_. And `/usr/local/php` also gives error _/bin/sh: /usr/local/php: is a directory_. In the shared host they told me I had to put the php version in the route and I don't know if this is also necessary in VPS. When I introduce `php -v` in SSH I get `PHP 5.5.29 (cli)` so I understand the php version is 5.5.29. I will keep trying combinations of those routes...

Comment: `/usr/bin/php` I always use this path and always working.

Comment: That route gives my this error: _Status: 404 Not Found X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.29 Content-type: text/html No input file specified_ . I'm introducing this cron job in cpanel with the domain's user <domain@vps111222>. Perhaps I should try it with the root user?

Comment: Finally, with some good help I managed to sort it out. The correct sentence for the cron task in my VPS is: `php /home/mydomain/app/console api:import`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with some good help I managed to sort it out. The correct sentence for the cron task in my VPS is: `php /home/mydomain/app/console api:import`